# Position correct content Bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use responsive design in Bootstrap 3 with the help of Bootstrap 3 grid position as you can see I am using the same postion however for some reason the image won't stay with the text. It's a bit off to the left.

[image]

```css
.ha-bg-parallax {

    background: url(../image/bg.jpg) no-repeat fixed;

    -moz-background-size: cover;

    -o-background-size: cover;

    -webkit-background-size: cover;

    background-size: cover;

    height: 100vh;

    margin: 0 auto;

    width: 100%;

    display: table;

    vertical-align: middle;

}



.ha-bg-parallax .ha-parallax-body {

    display: table-cell;

    vertical-align: middle;

}



.ha-bg-parallax .ha-content-whitecolor {

    font-size: 17px;

    color: #ffffff;

    width: 45%;

    margin: auto;

}



.ha-bg-parallax .ha-diamond-divider-md {

    margin: 15px 0px;

}



.ha-bg-parallax .ha-heading-parallax {

    font-style: italic;

    font-weight: bold;

    text-transform: none;

    color: #ffffff;

    padding-bottom: 0px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">



<div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">

                <div class="ha-bg-parallax text-center block-marginb-none" data-type="background" data-speed="20">

            <div class="ha-parallax-body">
              <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
          <img class="img-circle img-responsive" alt="me" src="http://puu.sh/ndUaw/59e5207430.jpg">



          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
                <h1><span class="element"></span></h1>
                <a href="skype:edgaraxe">
                        <i class="fa fa-skype fa-3x"></i></a> <a href="https://keybase.io/edhusky">
           <i class="fa fa-key fa-3x"></i></a> <a href="https://github.com/edgaraxe">
                        <i class="fa fa-github fa-3x"></i> </a> <a href="https://bitbucket.org/edhusky/">
             <i class="fa fa-bitbucket fa-3x"></i></a> <a href="mailto: edhusky94@gmail.com">
                                  <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-3x"></i></a>

          </div>


        </div>


                <div class="ha-parallax-divider-wrapper">

                    <span class="ha-diamond-divider-md img-responsive"></span>

                </div>



            </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this css:

```
.img-responsive {
    margin: auto;
}
```

Bootstraps `.img-responsive` style is defined as

```
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

The `margin: auto` addresses the lack of centering in the style.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `margin: auto;` to the image to center it within the div. This should give you the desired effect of keeping it centered above the icons.

I added `img.img-circle.img-responsive { margin: auto; }`. See edited version.

```css
img.img-circle.img-responsive { margin: auto; }

.ha-bg-parallax {

    background: url(../image/bg.jpg) no-repeat fixed;

    -moz-background-size: cover;

    -o-background-size: cover;

    -webkit-background-size: cover;

    background-size: cover;

    height: 100vh;

    margin: 0 auto;

    width: 100%;

    display: table;

    vertical-align: middle;

}



.ha-bg-parallax .ha-parallax-body {

    display: table-cell;

    vertical-align: middle;

}



.ha-bg-parallax .ha-content-whitecolor {

    font-size: 17px;

    color: #ffffff;

    width: 45%;

    margin: auto;

}



.ha-bg-parallax .ha-diamond-divider-md {

    margin: 15px 0px;

}



.ha-bg-parallax .ha-heading-parallax {

    font-style: italic;

    font-weight: bold;

    text-transform: none;

    color: #ffffff;

    padding-bottom: 0px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">



<div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">

                <div class="ha-bg-parallax text-center block-marginb-none" data-type="background" data-speed="20">

            <div class="ha-parallax-body">
              <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
          <img class="img-circle img-responsive" alt="me" src="http://puu.sh/ndUaw/59e5207430.jpg">



          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
                <h1><span class="element"></span></h1>
                <a href="skype:edgaraxe">
                        <i class="fa fa-skype fa-3x"></i></a> <a href="https://keybase.io/edhusky">
           <i class="fa fa-key fa-3x"></i></a> <a href="https://github.com/edgaraxe">
                        <i class="fa fa-github fa-3x"></i> </a> <a href="https://bitbucket.org/edhusky/">
             <i class="fa fa-bitbucket fa-3x"></i></a> <a href="mailto: edhusky94@gmail.com">
                                  <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-3x"></i></a>

          </div>


        </div>


                <div class="ha-parallax-divider-wrapper">

                    <span class="ha-diamond-divider-md img-responsive"></span>

                </div>



            </div>

        </div>
```